# mobx losing properties deep in an object

Tags: react-native, mobx

Apologies in advance for this awful question. I rather hope that an expert in the field will know what idiot thing I am doing wrong, if you need more info then please just ask!

I have a somewhat complex object I need to store using mobx.

```
export default class Field {
    @observable public key: string;
    @observable public fieldCoordinates: Coords;
    @obser... more and more properties.
```

Coords looks like

```
export default class Coords {
    @observable public id: string;
    @observable public coordinates: Array<LatLng>;
}
```

and LatLng

```
export default class LatLng {
    @observable public latitude: number;
    @observable public longitude: number;
}
```

In my store I have

```
@observable public fields: Array<Field> = new Array<Field>();
```

and in a `Save` method I use

```
 store.save("fields", toJS(this.fields));
```

However when I try and use the `coordinates` object to lay out my map I get an error

> Error while updating property 'coordinates' of view managed by: AIRMapPolygon

I get the data using this method (in the store)

```
@computed public get DataSource(): Array<LatLng> {
    return this.field.fieldCoordinates.coordinates.slice();
}
```

However when I inspect the `fields` array as it is going into the store it has been stripped of the LatLng array. (the list of points has 9 things in an array, but the data is gone (I have opened up the first element and it only has the `proto` not the data.)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GQtkiGu.png]

I guess that I am doing something wrong, or using the wrong types or something simple... can you steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise this type of question is not that tractable on here...

but if you are some future person with a similar issue then I have 'fixed' it by removing the `@observable` from the coordinate arrays and objects.

Clearly this halts the mobx state management for these objects, but that is fine for my case and it now does work for me.

Further news:
If fact a new requirement meant I did need these to be observable.

I have now this line for an array

`public readonly coordinates = observable<LatLng>([]);`

and I have fixed my previous problem which I now think was related to using some `setState()` where I had not completed the move to mobx and it was that that was breaking my page and expectations.

Don't mix different state management ideas!